# The curve passing through the points of intersection of $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

> The curve passing through the points of intersection of $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ and $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ represents a pair of straight lines which are:
>   (a) equally inclined to the x axis
>   (b) perpendicular to each other
>   (c) pass through a fixed point
>   (d) none of the above

I am having a problem comprehending the question. How can the 2 intersection points define a whole curve? How can 2 distinct lines be defined by 2 intersection points?

Comment: you will have for points of intersection. That cans give you two lines

Comment: @Arnaldo I tried it on geogebra and it gives only 2 points of intersection

Comment: Be carefull to believe in geogebra. You will have an ellipse and a circle. You can get four points, it depends on the values of $a,b,c,g,f$

Comment: @Arnaldo ah right...forgot that an ellipse and a circle can intersect in more than 2 points lol...you can post this as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0\to (x+g)^2+(y+f)^2=g^2+f^2-c$$

which can be a circle.

[image]

That is a picture about what is happening according to the values of $a,b,c,f,g$.

Can you go forward?